# trying to loop through the array of objects and find the match

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i have below object structure like as in below image and i am trying to match with the inner object property(like massing type id) with the existing ID and if it is match i need to get the name of that object and push it to array and set that array in state object,

[image]

and the code is looks like as below

```
    Object.values(constructionSets).forEach(item => {
        console.log(item);
        const constructionSetItem = [];
        if (
          item.ashraeClimateZone?.id === ashraeClimateZoneId &&
          item.massingType?.id === massingTypeId &&
          item.sourceOfData?.id === energyCodeId
        ) {
          setConstruction(constructionSetItem.push(item.name));
        }
      });
```

and when i log `item` i am getting array of objects instead of single object, could any one please let me know where i am doing wrong with the above code?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the `constructionSets` value passed into `.values()`?

Comment: `constructionSets` appears is already an array, so `Object.values(constructionSets)` should return back an identical array and the `console.log(item);` is log of each object.

Comment: @mmason33  that is just array of 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in the information you gave, that `constructionSets` variable is already an Array so to loop it, you just need to do:

```
constructionSets.forEach(item => {...})
```